# Create pipeline with Gitlab API. Getting 500

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I'm trying to create a new pipeline using https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline but the `variables` param is a bit confusing. Are they expecting a long json string that's url encoded and stuffed into that thing? I'm used to passing data in the body so this feels very restricted.

If I call this? `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{YOUR PROJECT ID}/pipeline?variables=%255B%257B%2522variable_type%2522%253A%2522variable%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522SCHEME%2522%252C%2522value%2522%253A%2522fooBAR%2522%257D%255D&ref=feature/some-cool-feature` it just 500's.

I'm sure I'm doing something silly but does anyone have an idea?

I'll mention that it works great without the `variables` param.

Comment: How do you call this, do you use postman or something similar or do you just open that link in the browser?

Comment: Postman works, but I'm building a custom native app. If you look at the docs, there is a required header for the token so once you add that you can call it however you want. Here is a curl example:

`curl --location --request POST 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{YOUR PROJECT ID}/pipeline?ref={YOUR BRANCH NAME}&variables=%5B%7B%22variable_type%22:%22variable%22,%22value%22:%22fooBAR%22,%22key%22:%22SCHEME%22%7D%5D' \
--header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: {YOUR TOKEN}'`

Comment: i am asking because as long as i provide the data via body (curl `--data`) it works fine without any issue - but as soon as i try to add it as url parameter i also get an 500

Comment: Oh interesting! Body works for me too. I thought the docs were saying to pass it in as a query param.

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @simon-schrottner for the nudge. I thought the docs were saying to pass in the variables as a query param but passing them in as the body were a lot simpler.